# How to use optional path parameter with react_router_dom v 6+

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to declare a path with an optional path parameter with React-router-dom version 6.2. I use this one but is not working

```
        <Route path="/somepage/:id?" element={<CartPage/>}/>
```